# I've installed EOAUTH extension, i can authenticate with google, but I'm wondering how to get user information after that

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

Wishing You a Happy New year I start with my first problem of the year

here's what I do in login method of user controller:

```
Yii::import('ext.eoauth.*');

            $ui = new EOAuthUserIdentity(
                            array(
                            //Set the "scope" to the service you want to use
                                            'scope'=>'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                                            'provider'=>array(
                                                            'request'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
                                                            'authorize'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
                                                            'access'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                                            )
                            )
            );

            if ($ui->authenticate()) {
                    $user=Yii::app()->user;
                    $user->login($ui);
                    $this->redirect(array('loggedin'));
            }
            else 
                    throw new CHttpException(401, $ui->error);
```

its logged and in place of name it display the token key.. i need to get email at least to store it to db... Please help me out.. thanks in advance

Comment: did you try Yii::app()->user->name; ?

Comment: Yes.. It is giving name has **Guest** In need username or mail id

Comment: do you get logged in successfully?

Comment: Yes.. its logged in and its displaying key in place of name..I checked this class EOAuthUserIdentity where getName methode is has below  public function getName() {
        return $this->provider->token->key;
    }.. So it is returning key.. i changed it to name.. it will display error

Answer (score 0):

In the **UserIdentity** class, You need to write a line i.e

```
$this->setState('name', 'value');
```

This is used to set the `Yii::app()->user->name
so if you set it as

```
$this->setState('name', $record->email);
$this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
```

in your UserIdentity class then **Yii::app()->user->name** will return you the email or whatever you want

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong ... In the example we are calling EOAuthUserIdentity class...we will not get any  $record->email inside that.. Which value i need to set to name

Comment: replace **$record->email** with the value you want to set.  It was just an example

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot to get user detail by using above code.. Unfortunately I failed.. Then I started with eauth integration..I downloaded the demo example in the url and added extension to my extension folder inside protected and configured the main.php.. I got integration of more than 10 login integration.. I commented the services extension inside component  tag  in main.php to get Google and Yahoo login integration.. It works... Which made me to access the user name also.. Thanks for support..
[demo of eauth](http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo/login)

For integration find the link below
[Integration link for eauth](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth)